# How can I keep the cursor on username with Get-Credential?

Tags: powershell, passwords

When running `$Cred = Get-Credential 'MyDomain.com\'` it automatically moves the cursor to the password input. (See image below)

[image: Powershell Credential Prompt: Cursor on password input]

How can I display it with the domain already provided through the script but have the cursor still on the User Name input like this:

[image: Powershell Credential Prompt: Cursor on user name input]

This would mostly for convenience of less clicks during the running of said script. This way I can provide the domain name or just machine name to specify the local host and all the user has to enter is the user account name. I would like them not to have to click back on the user name input.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible with `Get-Credential`. However you could use `Read-Host` and `Read-Host -AsSecureString` to generate two different prompts, and use those inputs to create a `PSCredential` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's basically no way of handling it directly so you've got a few options (most of them a bit hacky).

First option, don't specify a User Name. This leaves it blank and the cursor starts there. However this then relies on the users entering the domain they are connecting to, if they don't you'll either need to error trap it or extract the details from the credential and create a new one with the correct domain (if known).

Next you could send a Shift+Tab via sendkeys after loading the credential prompt. This is a bit trickier since it'll involve starting a job with a timer, then launching the credential prompt and hoping they line up. Hopefully you've got fast machines.

```
start-job {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    start-sleep -m 100
    [system.windows.forms.sendkeys]::sendwait("+({TAB})")
    [system.windows.forms.sendkeys]::sendwait("{RIGHT}")
}
$Cred = Get-Credential 'MyDomain.com\'
```

Lastly you've got the option of writing your own dialogue in Winforms, or just handling it in the console (if shown). This is a pretty open course of action with thousands of answers so best to research it on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Never thought of trying to send the Shit+Tab to the credential prompt. Ill go for that solution. Now I need to figure out how to grab the handle of the Get-Credential.

Answer (score 0):

You could also leverage the `-Message` parameter of `Get-Credential` to pass a message with the expected format. Something like "Please enter your credentials in format 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'."

For example:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your credentials in format 'DOMAIN\USERNAME'."
```